# Click an <li> to behave like a label

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a list of items inside of `<li>` tags in a search tray. I want the user to be able to tap anywhere inside of the `<li>` tag to toggle the checkbox in the same way that tapping a related label toggles a checkbox.

This is the height and width of the entire `<li>`:
[image]

This is the height and width of the label:
[image]

This is how they are set up:

```
<ul id="catalogs" class="list-group collapse in">
     <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="catalog in catalogs">
          <input type="checkbox" id="{{catalog.id}}" name="{{catalog.id}}" ng-model="searchParams.catalogs[catalog.id]" ng-click="refreshCriteria()" />
         <label for="{{catalog.id}}">{{catalog.title}}</label>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Just add `for="your_id"` inside the `<li>`

Comment: Put the input inside the label?That would work.

Comment: why dont you just add the `ng-click="refreshCriteria()"` inside your `<li></li>`

Answer (score 1):

you may use display, position and text-indent

```css
label {
  display:block;
  text-indent:1em;
  }
input {
  position:absolute;
  }
li {
  /* demo purpose */ border:solid;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="catalogs" class="list-group collapse in">
     <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="catalog in catalogs">
          <input type="checkbox" id="{{catalog.id}}" name="{{catalog.id}}" ng-model="searchParams.catalogs[catalog.id]" ng-click="refreshCriteria()" />
         <label for="{{catalog.id}}">{{catalog.title}}</label>
     </li>
 </ul>
```